# Windows 8 Metro app, how to create this selected box style

Tags: c#, xaml

How is this style created or where can i find it?. (so that i only have to change the colors)
I mean the style in this picture of how the maps app is selected with the check mark in the corner.
I would really like to use this in an app, and I've seen it done in a few others too, but after hours of searching i havent fount anyway to do it. i cant seem to find how to create it.

[image]

If anyone can help me with this i would be very thankfull :)

Comment: Are you in a Windows 8 application, or a WPF one?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. So what you're referring to is built into many of the style templates for various controls for the Selected State of that control in the VisualStateManager. Usually named something like "SelectingGlyph" for the checkmark, and a border etc to give the little outline box which you will have to reproduce in your own templates. You can look at the default style templates for as example a ListBoxItem in windows store apps for an example. If you give it a shot on your own and run into troubles, let us know and we'll sort you out. Cheers